# Is there a way to "bump" deletion votes?

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools, vote-to-delete

There exist [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566823/what-are-triggers-in-sql-can-anyone-explain-with-examples) [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930000/how-can-i-add-jboss-5-1-0-ga-server-to-eclipse-3-3-0-europa) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006804/video-dictionary-using-php) that are closed, and really ought to be deleted, but only have one delete vote (from a while ago).

It seems that after a certain time, delete votes fall off the [delete vote tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days) page because they're too old or something.

There are a few possibilities that I can see:

- Is there a way to "bump" these votes so they can get considered for additional delete votes?
- Could the delete vote tools page show the "most votes" section sorted first by delete vote count and then by delete vote age (oldest first)? The "recent votes" section would continue to show the votes by newest vote first. Currently the "most" and "recent" lists show largely the same questions.
- Delete votes currently do not appear to expire (unlike close votes). If they were to expire, I could re-cast the delete vote and it would effectively bump it.

(If you're curious, I have a tool I wrote that helps keep track of old questions on their way to the deletion bit bucket. Old questions that are marked for deletion but don't get deleted hang around reminding me that they exist.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three ideas:

- coordinate in https://chat.stackoverflow.com or http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com so you can delete old stuff more effectively
- urge other 10k users to follow the deletion vote page on the 10k tools
- flag it for moderator attention. I speak only for myself, but I *love* deleting crappy stuff and I will be happy to oblige. I'm guessing a few other community mods feel similarly.

Comment: Is the "low quality" flag reason sufficient for these?

Comment: @greg probably, if it's clear and doesn't have a bunch of answers / upvotes which would give me pause on deletion

Comment: I don't think it's just you.  I have had many flags answered with a deletion.

Comment: Flagging works great, cheers :)