# Do delete votes ever expire?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

Lately, I've been casting a lot of delete votes on old questions, but I find myself pretty much alone in doing so. So, I would like to know if I should stop bothering.

Do those delete votes expire at all, like close and reopen votes?

Comment: I don't think they currently do, but I have no particular citation for that theory.

Comment: Personally, I look a lot at the "Recent Delete Votes" page and contribute where necessary, and so seem to a few others. So you're not alone :)

Comment: @minitech Talking about [gaming.se] here, I am in no position to delete questions on SO.

Comment: @lunboks: Well, never mind then! :)

Comment: I'm with @Cody here, from quick look on questions on SO with delete votes, looks like many of the votes were cast long time ago and it's still waiting for more votes. For example [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355338/fed-up-with-my-programming-job-what-should-i-do) got 3 votes already, and waiting for 8 more before it's actually deleted.

Comment: @Sha: I don't think those votes were cast so long ago. The past few weeks, skaffman has been going through and retagging a bunch of career-related questions that are now off-topic for SO (but too old to migrate to Programmers). Since those edits bump them up to the top, users like myself have been casting close/delete votes—in fact, I assume that's his motivation. Anyway, it's unlikely that those delete votes have been there since the question was asked 2-3 years ago.

Comment: @Cody not 2-3 years ago, I was thinking since it was closed.

Comment: @Gilles where did you take that information from? Any official source?

Comment: @Gilles Eh, you just [added that in](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5222/25). If you have that on good authority, why not answer this question, and we can link to it from the FAQ post?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd, lunboks: my own experience, and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87037/is-there-a-way-to-bump-deletion-votes). If there was an expiration date, it would be more than 30 days.

Comment: @Gilles Well, all signs point to "no", but it could be a really long expiry time, to the tune of months. Could be a sliding expiration type of deal, where if votes trickle in at a steady pace, they won't expire. Could be that a certain amount of activity/views is required for them to expire (which I believe is the case for close votes).

Comment: @Gilles in the linked questions he says "It seems that after a certain time, **delete votes fall off** the delete vote tools page" - so what made you think it means delete votes never expire? Sorry, but still prefer to have official response or solid proof. (e.g. question you voted to delete long time ago and still got this one delete vote)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Delete votes don't expire, but they fall off the `/tools?tab=delete` list after 30 days (because the list is restricted to 30 days at most). I know I've seen questions that had a delete vote that had fallen off that list, which puts the minimum possible expiration time at 30 days. That's it for the physics, now for the sociology: sure, there could be complex rules, but why would SE bother implementing complex rules that no one would care about and that never even got a mention on meta?

Comment: @Gilles fair enough, sounds convincing.. hope Jeff or other developer can make it official. :)

Comment: By the way, I don't think this is answered, but that guess is probably right and I don't care enough to try and get this reopened.